# Cannot see prints with python-tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, printing, tensorflow

I have the following program written in python:

import tensorflow as tf

def main(_):
  print(something)

if **name** == 'main':
   tf.app.run()

Either running it with bazel or not, I cannot see the output of print function. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the last line, which should be

```
if __name__ == '__main__': tf.app.run()
```

(note: __main__ instead of main)... This code works for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def main(_):
    print("something")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```